# Why use Thestrals to pull the carriages and not magic?

Tags: harry-potter

While doing some research for [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253488) I found out that there is a spell that can propel boats forward:

> "Seems a shame ter row, though," said Hagrid, giving Harry another of his sideways looks. "If I was ter — er — speed things up a bit, would yeh mind not mentionin' it at Hogwarts?"
>
> "Of course not," said Harry, eager to see more magic. Hagrid pulled out the pink umbrella again, tapped it twice on the side of the boat, and they sped off toward land.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*: Chapter 6 - "The Journey from Platform Nine and Three-Quarters"</sub>

If there's a spell to propel a boat forward it seems incredibly likely that there is *also* a spell that could move a carriage.

**So why does Hogwarts use Thestrals to pull the carriages and not magic?**

Comment: Madness this way lies. Why do anything except purely by magic?

Comment: It's generally a mistake to try and find consistency in the HP universe. But how about this: moving on water is easy as you just go in a straight line and don't have to avoid anything else; moving a carriage on land is much harder, especially with loads of other carriages around at the same time.

Comment: Why not use horses like muggle scum

Comment: I'd imagine it's a tradition; after all, the first years do boat across the lake by magic instead of using the carriages.

Comment: Maybe Hagrid — who we know owns at least part of the responsibility for getting students from the train up to the school — just thought using thestrals was cool? 

Comment: @DanielRoseman: In particular, I wonder how much _oversight_ the boats require. When Hagrid is in the boat, the boat is moving at his direction. It could be that when there's a flotilla, someone is overseeing it: it's easy on the water, where all boats are in sight. The carriages take a winding road however, may be quite harder to oversee.

Comment: I imagine it's a matter of pride - look at us, we have a whole herd of Thestrals.

Comment: Thestrals move at the speed of plot.

Comment: They same way people people keep on listening to LPs, while they can just carry around their music on their phones. It's a mixture of style, habit and preference. The fact that everything can be replaced by an intangible magic spell, doesn't mean it has to.

Answer (score 2):

### Officially, Hagrid is not allowed to use spells

> "Be grateful if yeh didn't mention that ter anyone at Hogwarts," he [Hagrid] said. "I'm - er - not supposed ter do magic, strictly speakin'. I was allowed ter do a bit ter follow yeh an' get yer letters to yeh an' stuff - one o' the reasons I was so keen ter take on the job -" -- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, pg. 69

So for Hagrid, an obvious display of wizardry in front of many witnesses is right out. Carriages drawn by Thestrals on the other hand are a perfect match for his occupation as Game Keeper.

Also, in the same book the first-years *are indeed* ferried from the train platform to Hogwarts by magic -- magic boats, albeit this time not propelled by a spell performed by Hagrid. He only gives the command "Forward", which either triggers a prepared spell or tells some wizard (who is not explicitly mentioned in the book) to bring the boats to Hogwarts. As mentioned in "The Prisoner of Azkaban", this is a tradition at Hogwarts:

> Harry, Ron and Hermione turned and saw the gigantic outline of Hagrid at the other end of the platform, beckoning the terrified-looking new students forward for *their traditional journey across the lake.* -- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, pg. 97, emphasis by me

And of course: Aren't thestrals magic, too?

Comment: I don't think this really answers my question on the use of Thestrals over the use of magic. I know Hagrid can't do magic, but he's not present when the carriages set off. Your second quote again doesn't really explain the use of Thestrals over the use of magic, it just points out it was a tradition for first-years to use the boats.